# HashTable и её размер

Tags: java, хеширование, java-hashmap, hashmap

Какой размер у хэш-таблицы по умолчанию? У ArrayList к примеру 10 элементов потом идет расширение по формуле (размерСтарогоМассива * 1.5) + 1, а как обстоят дела у хэш-таблицы? Какой размер по умолчанию и как я понял расширение происходит вдвое.

Comment: Что документация об этом пишет? Если ничего, то размер может варьироваться от реализации виртуальной машины \ конкретного алгоритма хеш таблицы.

Answer (score 1):

В HashTable по умолчанию 11 бакетов

```
/**
 * Constructs a new, empty hashtable with a default initial capacity (11)
 * and load factor (0.75).
 */
public Hashtable() {
    this(11, 0.75f);
}
```

[source code HashTable](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/Hashtable.java)

В HashMap - 16

```
/**
 * Constructs an empty <tt>HashMap</tt> with the default initial capacity
 * (16) and the default load factor (0.75).
 */
public HashMap() {
    this.loadFactor = DEFAULT_LOAD_FACTOR; // all other fields defaulted
}
```

[source code HashMap](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java)

Answer (score 0):

А в сырцы глянуть?

```
public Hashtable() {
        this(11, 0.75f);
    }
```

Comment: То есть 11 элементов или что?

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]